# MySQL import from .txt file

Tags: mysql, import, load, truncated

I've created a table with these properties:

```
create table if not exists vevok(
    id varchar(4) primary key,
    nev varchar(20) not null,
    varos varchar(20) not null,
    regisztralas date not null,
    koltott int unsigned not null 
) default charset=utf8 collate utf8_hungarian_ci;
```

and after that, I wanted to import datas from a .txt file. It was successful, but I realized that from the first column of the first record has truncated.

Here's what I used for loading table.

```
load data local infile 'C:/Users/adam/Downloads/vasarlok.txt' into table vevok
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

Result:

```
A00 Késmárki Edvárd Budapest    2010.11.06  49900
```

Expected:

```
A001    Késmárki Edvárd Budapest    2010.11.06  49900
```

In the first cell there isn't number 1 at the end of the data. Any other data was loaded successfully and appears correctly.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
load data local infile 'C:/Users/adam/Downloads/vasarlok.txt'
into table table_name
fields terminated by ',' ignore 1 lines 
(@col1,@col2,@col3,@col4)
set 
table.column_name = @col1,
table.column_name = @col2,
table.column_name = @col3,
table.column_name = @col4;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!